# Fastest way to retreive bitArray part

Tags: vb.net, bitarray

The title says all. My current version is:

```
Public Function GetBitArrayPart(ByVal BitArray As BitArray, _
                                ByVal IndexStart As Integer, _
                                ByVal IndexEnd As Integer) As BitArray

    If IndexStart < 0 OrElse IndexEnd > BitArray.Length - 1 OrElse IndexEnd < IndexStart Then
        Return New BitArray(0)
    End If

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim outputBA As New BitArray(IndexEnd - IndexStart + 1)

    For i = 0 To outputBA.Length - 1
        outputBA(i) = BitArray(IndexStart + i)
    Next

    Return outputBA

End Function
```

I must specify that the sizes of lookup bitAarrays are big. I dont understand why using the `System.String` to store the same amount of information to retreive a part of that string is faster than using `BitArray`. For that reason I started to analize the performance of my functions.

Comment: `BitArray` stores bits and allows accessing each single one. A string stores characters, at 8 bits each, and does not allow accessing individual bits of a character, so the point of them storing the same amount of information and string being faster is moot. As for the speed, try [`CopyTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx) to an array of bytes, take a portion of that and pass to [the `BitArray` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xda43a(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @GSerg : +1 Now I understand the accessibility difference between those two types, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's going to be faster, but here is an implementation based on copy to an array and create a new BitArray from it:

```
Public Function GetBitArrayPart(ByVal BitArray As BitArray, _
                        ByVal IndexStart As Integer, _
                        ByVal IndexEnd As Integer) As BitArray

    If IndexStart < 0 OrElse IndexEnd > BitArray.Length - 1 OrElse IndexEnd < IndexStart Then
        Return New BitArray(0)
    End If

    Dim arr as Boolean()
    BitArray.CopyTo(arr, 0)
    Return new BitArray(arr.Skip(IndexStart).Take(IndexEnd - IndexStart).ToArray())

End Function
```

Comment: Tested, almost same speed. NB - with a small modification: `Dim arr(BitArray.Length - 1) As Boolean` Thank you.